# Issue with Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, bash, powershell, windows-10

Specifically on my shiny new Surface Pro 2017 (i5, 256GB, 8GB RAM). So I'm trying to set up my dev environment and I'm running into a bit of a snag.

It shows up as installed through Powershell -and I'm able to run Python fine through it- but when I try the same on my Bash and Hyper terminals, no luck. I'm realizing now that Bash is not pictured in the screenshot, but it says the same thing when I try to run python commands. Did my due diligence in searching through the Surface subreddit, Google, and of course, Stack.

Anyone know what could be the issue? 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8y43.png)

Comment: What is your OS version? When did you install the Bash on Windows? Did you install it after upgrading to the Creator´s update? Can you execute for example `notepad.exe` from inside the bash?

Comment: You have a 32 bit Windows version of Python installed and visible to the powershell. It has nothing to do with your Ubuntu subsystem, is not visible from there, and is irrelevant for your Ubuntu environment. In bash, try `ls /usr/bin/python*`, what do you see?

Comment: @n.m.That's not completely true: since the Creator's update one can call Windows executables directy from the bash.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for your responses! I tried out that call in bash, and I see a whole bunch of /usr/bin/python (s). Apologies for the layspeak.

My OS version is 10.0.15063. Not sure that I have actually installed the Creator's update, I just bought my Surface a couple of days ago and went through the standard system setup with whatever updates it provides. 

When I run `notepad.exe` inside bash, it says "unable to translate working directory. Using C:\Windows\system32", and then proceeds to open notepad.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best solution is to install `python` inside your bash environment, too. What is the main reason you even want to call the Windows version of python from the `bash`? If installing `python` inside the Ubuntu subsystem/the `bash` again, then you might try to find out the path to the `python.exe` inside your Windows installation and try to add these path to your `bash`'s path, too.

Comment: Definitely this. Running Windows python.exe from WSL inherits the console from bash, which configures it in a Unix virtual terminal mode, so command-line editing and history don't work in the REPL. This could be addressed in Windows Python by having it set the console mode and restore it on exit, but then if Python crashes or gets killed the console will be left in the wrong mode. Properly, this should be handled by WSL itself when it executes a Windows console program.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a huge favor and install Anaconda, and use command line prompt from now on and don't even Touch Powershell or bash.  It's windows not linux.  The reason I say anaconda is because it gives you a huge array of libraries and also you can create a virtual environment meaning if Python gets screwed on or corrupted at least your file paths will be okay.